# Reconnect SignaR client on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, signalr

In my scenario, I am using SignalR for login purpose.

If user one is logged in with username 'abc' and user two login with the username 'abc', user one will be kicked and redirect two login page.

But if user one is logged in and it refreshes the page and then user two tries to logged in user one will not get kicked. Because while refreshing user one has lost the connection. I tried lots of solutions like trying to reconnect on disconnect event, but its not working.

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: After page refresh I lost the connection to the client. And not able to call client method from my Hub.

Comment: Can you share the code inside Hub also the solution's link that you tried. I need it in detail to help you identify the exact solution.

Comment: Well just in case if you want both users to be logged in then don't use the username as identifier generate `GUID` for each session and use that for logging

Answer (score 0):

**Client Disconnection Scenarios**

> In a browser client, the SignalR client code that maintains a SignalR connection runs in the JavaScript context of a web page
>
> When the user closes a browser window or tab, or navigates to a new page or refreshes the page, the SignalR connection immediately ends because SignalR client code handles that browser event for you and calls the Stop method. In these scenarios, or in any client platform when your application calls the Stop method, the OnDisconnected event handler executes immediately on the server and the client raises the Closed event (the event is named disconnected in JavaScript)

[Disconnection Scenarios(Client & Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)